# Any help with the History of Guaranty Quality Supreme Fleetwood Bicycle 1963 – 64

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

Original Goodyear Wing Foot “175” tires hold air with very good tread and no dry-rot.  Wheels marked M.O. MFG. Co. (Murray Ohio Manufacturing Company).  Bendix RB2 Red Band Automatic 2 speed Hub. Union Diamond Tread Pedals made in Germany.  Handlebar Stem marked A.S. - 66.  Fenders and Chain are thick, sturdy.  Very nice Mesinger Seat made in USA

[image] 
 [image] 
 [image] 
 [image] 
 [image] 
 [image] 
 [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  It's not clear what your question is.  Could you [edit] this to make it more obvious what you're asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Everything Murray Bicycle](https://www.facebook.com/MurrayBicycle/posts/542048165851387) your serial number:
**M9501JX26172612** (Not sure about the "J". Best I could tell from the picture)
indicates that
M9 = 1969
The "X" begins a string that indicates who the bike was made for.
For example "X13" would be a Murray branded bike.
If you ordered enough bikes from Murray they would put your brand on the bike.
"X7" = BF Goodrich
"X10" = Westernflyer (Western Auto)
"X12" = All Pro (Kmart)

Your bike is "X26" so according to the chart it was made for "Guaranty (Guaranty Bicycle Company - St. Louis Mo.)

The Guaranty Bicycle Company or Guaranty Cycle Co. was a shop located in St Louis Mo.
Here is a scan of [their 1952 catalog](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/1952-guaranty-bicycle-supply-catalog.83499/). The badge on the cover is an older version of the head badge in the picture

At one time they were able to buy enough bikes from Murray to have their own brand.

According to the USPTO the [Guaranty trademark](https://uspto.report/TM/72287101) was owned by Donald O Rehm and it expired in 1996.

There is no bike shop named Guaranty Cycle Co. in St Louis today. I can find no information on the history of the shop.

Hopefully this information will enable others to find more details.

Comment: Thats great ifo - thanks.  SR

Comment: Mr. Donald Rehm was my Great Uncle!

Comment: @KristenDaley cool. Do you or anyone in your family have any information on his bike shop?

Answer (score 1):

I was brought to this thread after seeing a [ghost sign](https://www.stlouis-mo.gov/data/address-search/index.cfm?Handle=10049000060) on a warehouse on Chouteau's Landing, St. Louis. It's a fairly large building in a district of abandoned factories. As a cyclist this piqued my curiosity.

At least 4 addresses are associated with the business:
[1164 N Kingshighway](https://thecabe.com/forum/attachments/f53a7e4c-9f6b-47ed-83d8-b01e46ad7808-jpeg.1003168/) - now a church.
[108 North 12th Street (called Tucker Blvd today)](https://mohistory.org/collections/item/resource:605193) as of 1933, long since demolished for Southwestern Bell, now SLU Law School.
[Southwest corner of 20th at Olive](https://thecabe.com/forum/attachments/img114-1-jpg.604161/) had a tower with a 1800's big wheel bike on the top as of 1957. [Building Photo Here](https://thecabe.com/forum/attachments/img116-1-jpg.604163/) Demolished for a parking lot and now the site of the eyesore MLS stadium, who demolished buildings and threw small businesses out of the city.
[201-9 Chouteau](https://www.proteanpaper.com/scart_picture.cgi?comp=howiebik&pic=000000000000003318&part=000000000000005744) as of 1972. I think this was mostly their warehouse but by 1972 may have been their only location. This would have been a terrible retail location though as this part of town was desolate byt the 1970s. Building is now owned by the St. Louis housing authority since at least 1992.

And these brands:
The Original Guarantee Cycle Company
Guarantee Quality Supreme
Cardinal
Stutz

According to the 1952 [catalog][9] the founder George F Rehm Jr. lived from 1897-1947. Don Rehm ran the company as of 1952.

Does anyone know if they ever manufactured in-house? The location on Chouteau’s Landings suggests they may have.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid I'm not sure what additional information you're contributing to the history of the bike in the question (beyond what's already in the other answer); it seems like you're setting up a question of your own, in which case you should [ask it directly](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).